# How to convert a block into its class -Canarymod

Tags: java, minecraft

I have been programming a plugin to move someone up when they right click a sign with certain text on on it but to find the text I need to convert the Block class to the sign class and use the `getTextOnLine();` function here is my Java code
public class CowShooter extends EZPlugin implements PluginListener {

```
@Override
 public boolean enable() {  
Canary.hooks().registerListener(this, this);
return super.enable(); // Call parent class's version too.
}  

@HookHandler
public void SignChangeHook(BlockRightClickHook event) {
Player player = event.getPlayer();
Block block = event.getBlockClicked();

if (block.getType() == BlockType.SignPost || block.getType() == BlockType.WallSign) {
```

Bad code
`Sign sign = event.getBlockClicked();`

```
if (sign.getTextOnLine(1) == "TP") {
Location loc = player.getLocation();
int playerX = (int) loc.getX(); 
int playerY = (int) loc.getY(); 
int playerZ = (int) loc.getZ();
loc.setY(playerY+10); 
player.teleportTo(loc);
}
}        


}
}
```

Here is the folder that the source code is in [Source code for canarymod](http://zombrom.com/canary)

Comment: `Sign sign = (Sign)event.getBlockClicked();`?

Comment: Yes thx I'll check if the functions are integrated lol canary is better than bukkit

Comment: No it can't be converted java thinks it works but canary throws this errow java.lang.ClassCastException: net.canarymod.api.world.blocks.CanaryBlock cannot be cast to net.canarymod.api.world.blocks.Sign

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the co-ordinates of the block and set them in the sign class

```
Location loc = player.getLocation();
loc.setX(event.getBlockClicked().getX());
loc.setZ(event.getBlockClicked().getZ());
loc.setY(event.getBlockClicked().getY());
World world = loc.getWorld();

Sign sign = (Sign)world.getTileEntity(world.getBlockAt(loc));
```